# Добавить в словарь список двойной вложенности в качестве значения и сериализовать его элементы

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, словари

Прошу, подскажите. Есть переменная

```
response = [
    ('Строка1', [...], datetime.date(2017, 11, 3), datetime.date(2020, 11, 16), datetime.date(2020, 11, 16), 534531),
    ...,
    ('Строка999', [...], datetime.date(2018, 10, 31), datetime.date(2020, 8, 22), datetime.date(2020, 11, 13), 35448763)
]
```

Я хочу из нее сделать словарь с помощью `defaultdict(list)` и даты перевести в формат, пригодный для передачи в json. Однако, с помощью следующего кода:

```
r = defaultdict(list)
for i in response:
   tmp = i[1:]
   r[i[0]].append(tmp)
```

вместо такого словаря

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {
'Строка1': [[...], datetime.date(2017, 11, 3), datetime.date(2020, 11, 16), datetime.date(2020, 11, 16), 534531],
..., 
'Строка999': [[...], datetime.date(2018, 10, 31), datetime.date(2020, 8, 22), datetime.date(2020, 11, 13), 35448763]})
```

у меня получается словарь со вложенным кортежем, который только мешает:

```
 defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {
'Строка1': [([...], datetime.date(2017, 11, 3), datetime.date(2020, 11, 16), datetime.date(2020, 11, 16), 534531)],
     ..., 
'Строка999': [([...], datetime.date(2018, 10, 31), datetime.date(2020, 8, 22), datetime.date(2020, 11, 13), 35448763)]})
```

Таким образом, мне сейчас непонятны две вещи: как модифицировать код, чтобы не было вложенного кортежа, и как изменить даты, чтобы их принимал json?

Update: решилось все заменой метода append на extend и преобразованием дат в строку. Код выглядит так:

```
r = defaultdict(list)
for i in response:
    tmp = list(i[1:])
    r[i[0]].extend(tmp)
for i in r.values():
    i[1] = str(i[1])
    i[2] = str(i[2])
    i[3] = str(i[3])
```

Comment: Единственное, до чего я додумался, это заменить tmp = i[1:] на tmp = list(i[1:]), но в таком случае вместо списка двойной вложенности появляется список тройной вложенности, что лишнее.

Comment: попробуйте место `append` написать `extend`

Comment: `как изменить даты, чтобы их принимал json?` - проще всего в процессе преобразования в словарь вручную каждую дату приводить к нужному текстовому виду.

Comment: @insolor, а какой этот нужный вид? Есть ли какой-то нативный формат для json, на подобие питоновского datetime? Или можно просто даты преобразовать в строку?

Comment: @Danis, спасибо, вид стал правильным. Половина ответа есть)

Comment: @Сергей JSON ничего не знает про даты, нет никакого "правильного" формата даты для него (см. [What is the “right” JSON date format?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10286204/4752653)). Нужно преобразовать дату в текстовый вид, который понимает принимающая сторона ("получатель" вашего JSON).

Comment: @insolor, понятно, внес изменения в код и все нормально заработало. Хватило обычного преобразования в строку.

Comment: @Сергей вот просто str я бы не советовал - вам придется специально парсить потом такой формат. Лучше преобразовывать например к виду `'2018-10-31'` с помощью метода `.isoformat()`, дату парстится как `date.fromisoformat('2018-10-31')`.

Comment: @insolor, к счастью, это пока не проблема, сейчас - главное чтобы работало. Формат будет уже позже выбираться.